# simple numerical approximation to pde solution blows up

Tags: derivatives, partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, algorithms

I'm trying to solve the pde $u_t = i[\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}u_{xx}+\begin{pmatrix}3 & -1 \\ -1 & 3\end{pmatrix}u]$ where $0 \leq x \leq 1$, $0 \leq t$

with periodic boundary conditions, subject to the initial condition $u(0, x) = \begin{pmatrix}\cos(2\pi x)\\-i\sin(2\pi x) \end{pmatrix}$

Using finite difference forward scheme, also known as forward Euler scheme.

**What I tried and my results:**

For simplicity suppose $u(t,x) = \begin{pmatrix}f(t,x) \\ g(t,x)\end{pmatrix}$, then our system is $\begin{pmatrix}f_t\\g_t\end{pmatrix} = i\begin{pmatrix}g_{xx}+3f-g\\f_{xx}-f+3g\end{pmatrix}$

Our approximations for the derivatives are:

$f_{t}(t_j,x_i) \approx \frac{f(t_{j+1},x_i)-f(t_j,x_i)}{\Delta t}$, $f_{xx}(t_j,x_i) \approx \frac{f(t_j,x_{i+1})-2f(t_j,x_i)+f(t_j,x_{i-1})}{\Delta x^2}$ and the same for $g$, where $(t_j,x_i)$ are grid points.

Let's look at our first equation, the one for $f_t$. Plugging in the derivative approximations we get $f(t_{j+1},x_i) = f(t_j, x_i
)+i(\frac{\Delta t}{\Delta x^2}(g(t_j,x_{i+1})-2g(t_j,x_i)+g(t_j,x_{i-1}))+3\Delta t f-\Delta tg)$

In simpler, shorter matrix form:

$$\begin{pmatrix}f(t_{j+1},0)\\f(t_{j+1},\Delta x)\\ \vdots\\f(t_{j+1},1)\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}f(t_{j},0)\\f(t_{j},\Delta x)\\ \vdots\\f(t_{j},1)\end{pmatrix}+i\begin{pmatrix}-\frac{2\Delta t}{\Delta x^2}&\frac{\Delta t}{\Delta x^2} & 0 & \dots & 0 & \frac{\Delta t}{\Delta x^2}\\ \frac{\Delta t}{\Delta x^2}& -\frac{2\Delta t}{\Delta x^2}&\frac{\Delta t}{\Delta x^2}& \dots & 0 & 0\\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \dots & \vdots & \vdots \\\frac{\Delta t}{\Delta x^2} & 0 & 0 & \dots & \frac{\Delta t}{\Delta x^2} & -\frac{2\Delta t}{\Delta x^2}\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}g(t_j,0) \\ g(t_j, \Delta x) \\ \vdots \\ g(t_j, 1)\end{pmatrix} + 3i\Delta t\begin{pmatrix}f(t_j, 0) \\ f(t_j, \Delta x) \\ \vdots \\ f(t_j, 1)\end{pmatrix}-i\Delta t\begin{pmatrix}g(t_j, 0) \\ g(t_j, \Delta x) \\ \vdots \\ g(t_j, 1)\end{pmatrix}$$

And also the respective system for $g$ at time $t_{j+1}$. And that's exactly what I did. I put in the values we know for $t = 0$, and then i do one step (forward in time) in $f$, one step in $g$, and so on, until $t=1$.

My issue is that my solution seems to explode. The result I get for $f$ at $t=1$ oscillates wildly between $10^{160}$ to $-10^{160}$, and the same for $g$. For this I used $\Delta x = \frac{1}{16}$ and $\Delta t = 0.25 \cdot \Delta x^2$.

Does this result make sense? where is the problem? What is the actual solution?

Comment: Have you tried to analyze the ode at hand? Is the problem well-posed? Second, Euler scheme can be unstable, so you need to analyze the stability of the scheme as well.

Comment: @VorKir I'm not sure I'm experienced enough or knowledgable enough to perform that analysis. I suppose that's why I posted the question.

Comment: I see. My point is that you should be aware that for illposed problems no stable approximations exist. From practical standpoint you can try the following. Try to fix the space step and start decreasing the time step. See if you observe instability or it stops after the time step is small enough. Second, you can rewrite your approximation in the matrix form $u_{n+1} = A u_n$ where $n$ is the time step and check the eigenvalues of A w.r.t to the time step $\tau$. Or you can perform the von Neumann analysis by looking at how you method behaves for different harmonics.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_stability_analysis for the reference. And you can also look from the theoretical side. Try to determine the type of the system, after you rewrite it in real form, e.g.